# regex to extract some values in syntax

Tags: regex

Can someone please help me with regex for the string between `'request='` and `'">'`?

For example for `request=this_is_the_text_I_need">` regex would return `'this_is_the_text_I_need'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:  `request=(.+?)">`. It will extract any text which is between `request=` and `">`. It should allow you to access the value through the use of regex groups.

Note: I am assuming that you are using the single quotes to denote the answer you are after, and do not want them as part of the returned value.

Comment: This is whacked. I actually had the correct regex as you've posted here. Problem was JMeter had an '=' in the answer and this confused the hack out of me. It was only afterwards that I realised that '=' was not part of the answer! :-( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
/request=([^"]+)">/

request= : Match "request="
([^"]+)  : Match anything other than '"' one or more and add it to first group.
```

Python:

```
>>> re.match('request=([^"]+)">', 'request=this_is_the_text_I_need">').group(1)
'this_is_the_text_I_need'
```

Comment: The last section should be `">` and not just `>`.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is a lookahead and lookbehind statements. For example, in `grep`:

```
$> echo 'request=this_is_the_text_I_need">' | grep --only-matching --perl-regex "(?<=request=).*(?=\">)"
this_is_the_text_I_need
```

So `(?<=request=).*(?=\">)` consist of 3 parts:

- `(?<=request=)` - indicates that matched string will be after `request=`.
- `.*` - indicates that matched string could contain all posible symbols
- `(?=\">)` - indicates that matched string will be before `">`.

Comment: This solution worked when I tried it on my Ubuntu Linux, however it returned nothing when I tried it on RH 2.4.21-47.ELsmp Linux and it returned `Unmatched ".` when I tried it on RH 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5PAE.